# Unable to enter Excel upload data into SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to create a function to choose the type of file to be uploaded, and upload the Excel file data into a SQL Server database. Currently, the upload function is working as the file is saved into the `tempfile` path. But the data entered into the database table all turned out as NULL even though the file uploaded has data in it.

I'm not too sure on what is causing this as there are no errors, so I'd like some input on what I'm doing wrong and if I'm heading in the right direction with my code.

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
<label id="lbl_report" for=" report_upload" style="font-family:Calibri; 
    position:fixed;" >Report : </label>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="report_upload" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        CssClass="form-control">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Choice 1" Value="val1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=" Choice 2" Value="val2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=" Choice 3" Value="val3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=" Choice 4" Value="val4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label class="fa fa-upload" style="cursor:pointer;margin-left:5%;">
        <small ID="Small2" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;">Upload 
        file</small>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
            Style="display:none;" Width="400px" />
    </label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull- 
    right" OnClick="btnUpload" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="False" />
</div>
```

Part of the aspx.cs code

```
public void btnUpload(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    String strConnection =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    String path = Server.MapPath("/tempfile" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    String fileExt = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    if (FileUpload.HasFile) 
    {
        String tempfile = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") +
        FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tempfile/" + tempfile));

        String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " + path + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0; HDR = YES; READONLY = FALSE; '", path);

        using(OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString)) 
        {
            String ddlStr = report_upload.SelectedValue;

            //upload to db
            if (ddlStr == "val4") 
            {
                //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
                using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [SheetA$]", excelConnection)) 
                {
                    excelConnection.Open();

                    using(OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
                    {
                        using(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)) 
                        {
                            // Destination table name
                            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "[db].[dbo].[Datatbl]";
                            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                        }
                    }

                    excelConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help.

```
try {
    OpenFileDialog fBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();
    // With...
    "Excel files(*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*".FilterIndex = "Import data from Excel file";
    fBrowse.Filter = "Import data from Excel file";
    if ((fBrowse.ShowDialog() == Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)) {
        string fname;
        fname = fBrowse.FileName;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
                        + (fname + (";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\""))));
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select Columns names from [sheet$]", MyConnection);
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Ur table name.");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
        // If dataset is not empty Then write code here to insert values to DB.
        MyConnection.Close();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString);
}
```